# sap hana sps12 calculated column SQL engine invisible

Tags: hana

I'm a new worker in SAP HANA. 
When I'm trying to create a calculated column, I can't choose between column engine or SQL because nothing appear.
Here the image

[Crate a calculated colum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS9xK.png)

If anyone has an idea.

Regards

Etienne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no selection box for the execution engine then you're very likely using a too old version of HANA Studio.
One way to avoid this is to use the Web-based IDE instead.
Or, of course, install the matching HANA Studio for SPS 12.

Comment: Indeed its was a version'problem. I install again and the problem is solve, thanks